# How to convert 007898989 to 7898989 in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to convert `007898989` to `7898989` in Python using the following code:

```
long(007898989)
```

However this leads to the following error:

```
>>> long(007898989)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    long(007898989)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

How can I convert this number correctly?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *Literally* `long(007898989)`? The leading zero then makes it octal, which would make `8`s and `9`s invalid digits. But *why* are those zeros there?! What's wrong with `long(7898989)`?

Comment: octal in python 2 only. Invalid in python 3 whatever the digits are.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Good point. More information from OP is crucial.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, doing this:

```
a = 007898989
```

will raise the error `SyntaxError: invalid token`, the easiest way to convert to long would be:

**On Python 2**

```
a = long("007898989")
print a
```

Trying this cast on python 3 would give `NameError: name 'long' is not defined`, so, I'd say the best solution is the below one

**On python 2/3**

```
a = int("007898989")
print(a)
```

Comment: good point! `int("007898989")` works as well. I thought it would require the `lstrip()` but no.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: It doesn't need `lstrip` because the `int` constructor, unlike `int` literals, defaults to base 10, not automatic base detection based on prefixes. So the leading `0`s can't possibly be confused for anything else; you only have a problem if you pass the `base` argument as `0` (which would try to interpret as octal, and fail on the `8` and `9` digits). This isn't JavaScript, where we do terrible things like have the int parsing function default to heuristic base detection. :-)

Comment: @BPL: There is no reason to provide the explicit base; `base` defaults to `10` on both Py2 and Py3, so there is no portability gain by adding it.

Answer (score 0):

`007898989` is not a valid number in Python since numbers starting with a `0` are supposed to be octal numbers and cannot contain 8 or 9. For example `077` octal is the same as `63` decimal. In Python 2, you can write this code:

```
>>> 077
63
```

This could trigger some serious bugs if not handled carefully. Therefore, for Python 3, numbers with leading zero's are no longer allowed:

```
>>> 077
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    077
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Luckily, you can easily convert a numeric string with leading 0's in Python 2 to a long integer using this syntax:

```
long('007898989', base = 10)
long('007898989') # Since base defaults to 10 anyway
```

For Python 3 `int` already has unlimited precision, therefore long is not supported anymore. For Python 3, you can simply use:

```
int('007898989')
```

Comment: You don't need `base = 10` (the default?). `int('007898989')` is fine in Python 2.7 and 3. It's only in *code* such as `a=007898989` where it gets treated as  an invalid octal constant.

Comment: `base = 10` is not necessary but in any language it is error prone to use numbers with leading 0's, therefore I added it. It is a bit inconsistent that the python interpreter uses base 0 and `int` defaults to base 10. Just like `0b11` can be used in python but not as string argument to int except with `base = 2` or `base = 0`.

Comment: Not really. int(stringvar) is used for conversion of data representing an int that comes from an arbitrary source outside of Python's control, and the base default is 10. The leading zero may be generated by (say) a pea-brained microprocessor that hasn't got the firmware smarts to convert leading zeros to spaces. (or, from an hh:mm timestring where leading zeros are the norm). In contrast, `a=0644` in a `.py` file is a statement in the Python language and must follow Python's rules.

Comment: `0nnn` for octal was of course a language design mistake, so in Python3 `a=0644` is a coding error and you have to write the more legible `a=0o644` (or a=644 if you want decimal).

Comment: That pea-brained microprocessor might as well throw octal data out. I was talking about the interpreter being inconsistent, not long/int having base 10. I'm glad Python 3 at least fixed *that*. 0o is a weird looking, but much better prefix for octal numbers.